# I want player to rotate on Z axis when keydown then upon releasing it goes back to 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

Ok, so I am new to all of this what started as curiosity is now an obsessive hobby.
That being said I am very noob so I need help with this
I am making an endless runner with camera attached to the player and the view is from behind so it isnt a side scroller and I set motion on the Z axis going forward. I gave options to go left and right as well as up and down.
What I am hung up on is I would like the player on the Z (spaceship is the object) to slightly rotate left or right as you press the assigned keys and rotate back to 0 upon release
This is to simulate more of a dodging effect as you are playing as there is plenty of objects to avoid...
I have tried many thing to no success

here is my code and thanks for any help:

```
public float moveSpeed = 6;
public float leftRightSpeed = 5;
public float topBottomSpeed = 5;
static public bool canMove = false;

void Update()
{
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed, Space.World);
    
    if(canMove == true)
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            if(this.gameObject.transform.position.x > LevelBoundary.leftSide)
            {
                transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * leftRightSpeed);
            }

        }
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            if(this.gameObject.transform.position.x < LevelBoundary.rightSide)
            {
                transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * leftRightSpeed * -1);
            }
        }
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            if(this.gameObject.transform.position.y < LevelBoundary.topSide)
            {   
                transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * topBottomSpeed);
            }
        }
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            if(this.gameObject.transform.position.y > LevelBoundary.bottomSide)
            {
                transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * topBottomSpeed * -1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up your code and created rotation
Here is the result: https://www.veed.io/view/af1acd18-4bfb-42e6-aa5b-9b411b656793?sharingWidget=true&panel=share
And code:

```
        public float leftRightRotateValue = 10;
        public float rotationSpeed = 5;
        public float moveSpeed = 6;
        public float leftRightSpeed = 5;
        public float topBottomSpeed = 5;
        public static bool canMove = false;

        private void Update()
        {
            transform.Translate( Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed * Vector3.forward, Space.World);
    
            if(canMove) //if player can move
            {
                float horizontalInputAxis = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * -1;//input by axis ("a" button return -1, "d" button return 1, if player doesn't press any buttons return 0)
                float verticalInputAxis = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");//input by axis ("s" button return -1, "w" button return 1, if player doesn't press any buttons return 0)

                float playerXPos = gameObject.transform.position.x;
                float playerYPos = gameObject.transform.position.y;

                if (playerXPos > LevelBoundary.leftSide && playerXPos < LevelBoundary.rightSide)//if player between left and right sides
                {
                    transform.Translate(Time.deltaTime * leftRightSpeed * horizontalInputAxis * Vector3.left);
                }
                
                if (playerYPos > LevelBoundary.bottomSide && playerYPos < LevelBoundary.topSide)//if player between top and bottom sides
                {
                    transform.Translate(Time.deltaTime * topBottomSpeed * verticalInputAxis * Vector3.up);
                }
                
                Vector3 newRotation = transform.eulerAngles;//save current player rotation
                newRotation.z = leftRightRotateValue * horizontalInputAxis;//change new z axis value relative to horizontal input
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(newRotation), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);//smoothly rotate player
            }
        }
```

rotation code:

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(from.rotation, to.rotation, rotationTime);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude this gives me the effect i was looking for however the player is going through the boundary and by doing this it loses the ability to use inputs I am assuming because he drifts out of range in this case I will rotate left sink into floor and not be able to returnthe opposite direction I will study what you wrote and try to tweek it to work for me thanks again!